# WinForms ListViewGroup in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, xaml

Check this:

[image: ListViewGroup]

Can I add `ListViewGroup` in WPF? Or a equivalent to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouping can be used in WPF, for example:

```
<GroupBox Header="Example">
    <GroupBox.Resources>
       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedSource" Source="{Binding Items}">
           <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PropertyToGroupOn" />
           </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </GroupBox.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource GroupedItemsSource}" />
</GroupBox>
```

This will show a ListBox with its items grouped based on the property `PropertyToGroupOn`.

Answer (score 2):

You can host WinForms control inside WPF controls using the [`WindowsFormsHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) control. Alternately, a quick Google search revealed a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFGroupSortingListView.aspx) sample that may do what you want in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Grouping in WPF is usually done using [collection views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542.aspx)), how those groups are represented in an items control dependes on the [`GroupStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx) which can be adjusted to look like what you want.